# writing and reading object in a binary file

Tags: java, oop, file-handling, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am making a program where user inputs his/her info and it is written in the file in binary form and after that we ask for a name whose info we want to get from the file. In that I take all the inserted objects into a arraylist and then match the name with respective name corresponding to the objects

this is my code

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

class MyObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

    public MyObjectOutputStream(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        super(os);
      }

    @Override
    protected void writeStreamHeader() {}
}

interface IIITN {
    final String InstituteName = "IIIT Nagpur";
}

class Student implements Serializable
{
    String name;
    String RollNo;
    String branch;
    String gender;
    String Degree;

    Student(String name, String RollNo, String branch, String gender, String Degree) {

        this.name = name;
        this.RollNo = RollNo;
        this.branch = branch;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.Degree = Degree;
    }
}

class CSE implements IIITN {
    String name;

    public void input(File CSEStudent) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = sc.next();
        String RollNo = sc.next();
        String branch = sc.next();
        String gender = sc.next();
        String Degree = sc.next();
        Student s1 = new Student(name, RollNo, branch, gender, Degree);
        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(CSEStudent,true);
        MyObjectOutputStream obj = new MyObjectOutputStream(fs);
        obj.writeObject(s1);
        // obj.close();
    }

    public void display(File f) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream CS = new FileInputStream(f);
        
        // ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(CS);
        // ArrayList<Student> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        Student s = null;
        boolean isExist = false;
        ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(CS);
        while (!isExist) {
            try {
                // ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(CS);
                s = (Student) obj.readObject();
                if (s != null) {
                    System.out.println(s.name);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println();
                isExist = true;
               
            }
        }
    }

    public void setname(File f) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Enter the name of student");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.name = sc.next();
        ArrayList<Student> obj = new ArrayList<>();
        display(f);
    //     for (Student student : obj) {
    //         System.out.println(student.name);
    //     }
    //     System.out.println("Enter");
    //     for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++) {
    //        if((obj.get(i)).name == this.name) {
    //         System.out.println((obj.get(i)).name);
    //         System.out.println((obj.get(i)).RollNo);
    //        } else {
    //         System.out.println("Not Found");
    //        }
    //    }
    }
}



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        CSE c1 = new CSE();
        File f = new File("./CSE.txt");
        c1.input(f);
        c1.input(f);
        c1.setname(f);
    }
}
```

It is taking the info of the student and is writing it in the file but when it comes to read from the file it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720007
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:987)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:414)
        at CSE.display(Main.java:61)
        at CSE.setname(Main.java:82)
        at Main.main(Main.java:187)
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you override `writeStreamHeader` ? And please read about Java naming conventions, the code is a pain to read :-)

Comment: Err... you've overridden `writeStreamHeader()` without providing an implementation yet you're surprised that the header is corrupt and giving you an exception..?